# SendGrid SMTP integration with contact form

Tags: php, email, smtp, sendgrid

I want to use SendGrid SMTP services to send emails from my website's contact form. The submit button on the form just spits out a blank version of my website, with no emails sent to my inbox.

Here's the PHP code:

```
<?php

require("class.phpmailer.php");
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    // SMTP & Sendgrid settings
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->Host = "smtp.sendgrid.net";
    $mail->Port = "465";
    $mail->SMTPAuth = "true";   // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = "sendgrid username";
    $mail->Password = "sendgrid password";
    $mail->SMTPSecure = ''; // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted

    // Email headers and body
    $mail->SetFrom("abc@123.com");
    $mail->AddAddress("abc@123.com");

    // Form fields
        $Name = $_POST['Name'];
        $Email = $_POST['Email'];
        $Contact = $_POST['Contact'];
        $Message = $_POST['Message'];


    $mail->Subject  = "Message from yoursite.com";
    $mail->Body     = "You have a new message from your contact form on site.com \n \n Name: $Name \n Email: $Email \n Contact: $Contact \n Message: $Message";
    $mail->WordWrap = 50;


    if(!$mail->Send()) {
      echo 'Message was not sent.';
      echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
    else {
      echo 'Message has been sent.';
    }
header('Location: mywebsite.com');
 ?>
```

Comment: See here, `require("class.phpmailer.php"); $mail = new PHPMailer();`, if you want to use SendGrid API then why are you using PHPMailer library here? Read the documentation here, [https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/v2_Mail/php.html](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/v2_Mail/php.html)

Comment: Oh alright. So I need to use SendGrids PHP library. I've downloaded the Library, copied the sendgrid-php.php file to my root directory and added the following line of code to my php file:

require("sendgrid-php.php");

Is this what you're saying?

Comment: Yes. And on top of that, you have to refactor your code as well because none of PHPMailer related code will work with SendGrid API.

Comment: <?php

require("sendgrid-php.php");

    $sendgrid = new SendGrid("SENDGRID_KEY");
 $email    = new SendGrid\Email();

 $email->addTo("email address of recipient of the form")
       ->setFrom("email address")
       ->setSubject("Sending with SendGrid is Fun")
       ->setHtml("and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP");

$sendgrid->send($email);

Is this correct or am i missing something? Because it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please point me the documentation you're following, also from where you have downloaded SendGrid library i.e. *sendgrid-php.php* file?

Comment: Yes of course. The documentation link you sent me --> https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/v2_Mail/php.html

This is where I downloaded the library from --> https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php#installation

Comment: Have you replaced this `SENDGRID_KEY` with the actual API key?

Comment: Yes, I replaced it with the actual API key.

Comment: I've given an answer below, hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the step-by-step process to send emails using SendGrid API,

- Download the archived SendGrid library from [**Download Packaged Library**](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php#alternative-install-package-from-zip). Extract it and put it in your project directory.
- Go to [**https://app.sendgrid.com/settings/api_keys**](https://app.sendgrid.com/settings/api_keys) and create an API key for your account/application.
- Now comes to the coding part. Refactor your code in the following way,

  ```
  require_once('sendgrid-php/sendgrid-php.php');

  $from = new SendGrid\Email(null, "SENDER'S_EMAIL_ADDRESS");
  $subject = "Hello World from the SendGrid PHP Library!";
  $to = new SendGrid\Email(null, "RECEIVER'S EMAIL ADDRESS");
  $content = new SendGrid\Content("text/plain", "Hello, Email!");
  $mail = new SendGrid\Mail($from, $subject, $to, $content);

  $apiKey = 'YOUR_API_KEY';
  $sg = new \SendGrid($apiKey);

  $response = $sg->client->mail()->send()->post($mail);
  if($response->statusCode() == 202){
      echo "Email sent successfully";
  }else{
      echo "Email could not be sent";
  }
  ```

  Don't forget to change `SENDER'S_EMAIL_ADDRESS`, `RECEIVER'S_EMAIL_ADDRESS` and `YOUR_API_KEY` as per your requirement. On top of this, change the subject and body of the email as per your application's requirement.

---

**Sidenote:** In case anything goes wrong in the midway, use the following three response methods for debugging.

```
echo $response->statusCode();
var_dump($response->headers());
echo $response->body();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!! It worked!! Email sent successfully and received!
One last question, please. I want the contents of the email to be picked up from the contact form. How do I do that? Like for instance, I want the $from = new SendGrid\Email(null, "SENDER'S_EMAIL_ADDRESS"); to pick up the email value from the form.

Comment: @Anonymous Simply put the variable in place of `SENDER'S_EMAIL_ADDRESS`, that's it. Here's an example, `$from = new SendGrid\Email(null, $Email);`. Also, please *accept* the answer if it resolved your issue. [How to accept answer on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: Accepted. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Anonymous You're welcome! Glad I could help. Cheers! :-)

Comment: I'm really sorry to bother you again but the PHP variables aren't working :( I did exactly as you said.

Comment: @kfm1607 Did you put three debug statements I showed in the **sidenotes**? What is it showing?

Comment: 00array(14) { [0]=> string(25) "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request " [1]=> string(14) "Server: nginx " [2]=> string(36) "Date: Sun, 07 May 2017 20:06:25 GMT " [3]=> string(31) "Content-Type: application/json " [4]=> string(20) "Content-Length: 176 " [5]=> string(23) "Connection: keep-alive " [6]=> string(22) "X-Frame-Options: DENY " [7]=> string(58) "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://sendgrid.api-docs.io " [8]=> string(35) "Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST "

Comment: [9]=> string(87) "Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type, On-behalf-of, x-sg-elas-acl " [10]=> string(28) "Access-Control-Max-Age: 600 " [11]=> string(75) "X-No-CORS-Reason: https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/API/cors.html " [12]=> string(1) " " [13]=> string(0) "" } {"errors":[{"message":"Invalid type. Expected: object, given: array.","field":"from","help":"http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/errors.html#message.from"}]}

Comment: @kfm1607 Oh, I just realized that you can't put random email address in the sender's `$from` field, you can only put **your valid email address** which has been used during the creation of SendGrid account. However, you certainly can put **any valid email address** as receiver's address.

Comment: @kfm1607 I'm unable to access it. You have put it as *private paste*, please make it public. Also, as I said earlier, you can't put random email address in the sender's `$from` field, you can only put **your valid email address** which has been used during the creation of SendGrid account. However, you certainly can put **any valid email address** as receiver's address. Have you looked into this?

Comment: Sorry about that. Please check now: https://pastebin.com/vSCY55bW
Yes, I have. That still doesn't solve the issue of picking up the PHP variables from the HTML form.

Comment: I think my website is cursed. Nothing I do works for the PHP variables to work :( I've tried `$email` I've tried `$_POST['email']` I've changed the $from value to a valid send grid email address, I've used the correct API key, I used the code you sent me. Nothing works.

Comment: @kfm1607 I explored your issue further. It seems there are several things you're doing wrong in your code, for example, `new SendGrid\fname(...)`, `new SendGrid\contact(...)` etc. are all wrong, SendGrid library doesn't have a class named `SendGrid\fname` or `SendGrid\contact` etc. You have completely refactor your code in the following way, [https://pastebin.com/w7QBBqz2](https://pastebin.com/w7QBBqz2). I've tested this on my end, and it's working fine for me.

Comment: Very careful with this import: require_once('sendgrid-php/sendgrid-php.php'); You may need to add ./ or ../ depending upon the location you are having your sendgrid library

Comment: i dont understand where you put the downloaded library zip?

Comment: @TomChambers You can put the library in any location of your choice, you just have to give appropriate path in `require_once(...);`.