# Correct/Recommended Way to Send Email Through GoDaddy Hosting (PHP)

Tags: php, godaddy-api

I have been using GoDaddy to host a few websites I build in the past (Coded from scratch with HTML, CSS, PHP, JAVASCRIPT). Most of them are simple websites with the most complex code being the contact forms from which my clients receive emails. I have been using phpMailer to send these emails once a contact form is submitted.

Lately, I've built a new site for one of my clients and came across a problem where I could not get phpMailer to work - turned out I used a wrong Host, where it should have been the URL from cPanel I used my Domain name, simple mistake. However, in search of answers I contacted GoDaddy support and got connected to an "Email Expert(His Words)". He was unable to help me but keep repeating that phpMailer is trash and is really bad with sending emails from a live website. I do have few issues with phpMailer - main one being that emails can take upwards of 10 min to arrive in the mailbox after the form has been submitted, as well as the amount of time it takes to send an email (User click SEND from website and page will load for about 5-10 sec before re-directing to another page with success message).

My question here today is: What is the Best/Recommended and most used way to send email from a live website hosted by GoDaddy.

I came across posts from people who recommend PHP 'mail()' function. - I used it in the past but it has a lot of limitations like the lengths of the email, and for some reason, every time email containing any HTML was sent the email address would change to my cPanel username.

Any Information/Guided is appreciated as I would like to send my emails according to industry-standard rather than using 'Trash' Solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to submit emails through your website is using SMTP services like Sendgrid, Amazon SES, and Mailgun. There is a lot of services out there.

Here you can see a working example on [how to send using Sendgrid and PHPMailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43832198/sendgrid-smtp-integration-with-contact-form).

Comment: Thanks for response. These solutions seem to stick with phpMailer. Is this a standard way of sending emails thought online forms? If that is the case why not use Google SMTP which I believe is free?

Comment: @babis95 you actually can use Google SMTP but there is a [daily limit](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en) of messages you can send. Also those services usually optimize the deliverability. If your website or online service relies on it, Google SMTP might not be a good solution.